# How can I identify parts of a string as words and save them to use in a program later?

Tags: c++, c

For example, if I had a string like "cat dog fish bird", what could I do to isolate each individual word? (In case I wanted to check if the second word was dog, for example.)  I'd like to have it so that I can access each separate word/entity of the string in the code to follow. Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Comment: Just about any introductory C++ book will show how to do basic tokenization.

Comment: Possibly an array of strings?

Comment: There is something that separates all the words. Maybe you can use this to split the words and copy them into an array or even a vector.

Answer (score 1):

You can use C++ STL sstream to split the string as follows:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    string test("cat dog fish bird");
    istringstream s(test);
    vector<string>v;

    do
    {
        string str;
        s>> str;
        v.push_back(str);
    } while (s);

    for (int i=0;i<v.size();i++){

        cout<<v[i]<<endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```